# What two processes occur that dictate the microstructure of a polymer?

Tags: organic-chemistry, polymers

Firstly, I'm not 100% sure on what a microstructure is as our lecturer didn't explain it all too well. From what I've gathered, its the backbone structure of the polymer chain - but I may be wrong.

In relation to the question, I have a thought that chain-walking is a process that dictates the microstructure but am unsure as to what else could be.

The example I am using is {OSSO}-ZrBn2 to polymerize propylene with Zr and Hf being the metal centre options as shown below.[image: Catalyst]

Based on the catalyst, what processes would dictate the microstructure of the polymer?

[image: Reaction conditions studied]

Comment: You *are* wrong. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microstructure https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystallization_of_polymers

Comment: What is Bn?    ...

Comment: @Poutnik the image of the catalyst used has been added to the question

Comment: @Mithoron Can you provide any more clarification instead of just posting links? I'm a bit lost on what you want me to look at here.

Comment: @Karl I've completed the lecture course and there was a total of one slide on microstructures where they didn't give an explanation for it :/

Comment: What kind of lecture was that exactly?

Comment: The catalyst and reaction conditions dictate the backbone structure. Tacticity, number and size of side chains, Mw, Mw distribution, ... The backbone structure, together with "processing parameters" (temperature profile, flow, ...) influences what crystalline microstructure you get. Now what exactly is your question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144311/discussion-between-audrix-and-karl).

Comment: Nothing to chat about. You, and very probably your teacher, are using the term "microstructure" for something that is not usually called microstructure. Judging from that you're supposed to interpret the results of CP-MAS experiments, this is some quite advanced lecture. So please get clear with the nomenclature, and then update your questions so it makes sense. And also tell us what info about the polymerisation of propylene with these catalysts you get from the data presented. Otherwise I'm inclined to vote "close" because this is a homework question without any visible effort by the OP.